EhCache 3, how to use Objects as keys
When I read the cache it never finds the cached values, it always says "CacheInterceptor - No cache entry for key"  and recreates a key/value pair in the cache.  It doesn't matter what combination of parameters I use, it never finds anything in the cache that matches.  What am I missing?
I have:

a service with a @Cacheable get... that has three parameters for the key, two strings and a POJO type object.
Spring Boot 3
EhCache 3.10.8 (with jakarta classifier)
Caches are defined via xml
ehcache and org.springframework.cache log levels set to TRACE (to get the above message)

The configuration class (it reads in the .xml file ehcache.xml)
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

@Autowired
private javax.cache.CacheManager cacheManager;

}

application.yml
spring:
  cache:
    jcache:
      config: classpath:ehcache.xml

ehcache.xml (in src/main/resources)
...
<cache alias="cmsLabelsCache">
    <expiry>
        <ttl unit="seconds">10</ttl>
    </expiry>
    <heap unit="entries">10000</heap>
</cache>
....

The Service with a @Cacheable method
@Service
public class CMSPropertiesService {

@Cacheable(value = "cmsLabelsCache", key = "{#cmsSpecificRequest, #langAndMarket, #labelKey}")
public String getLabelWithReferences(@NotNull String cmsSpecificRequest, @NotNull LangAndMarket langAndMarket, @NotNull String labelKey) {
    String label = "[" + cmsSpecificRequest 
                 + ", " + langAndMarket.toString() + ", " + labelKey + "]";
    return label;
}

the LangAndMarket class
    public static class LangAndMarket {

    private String lang;
    private String market;

    ... getters, setters, constructors. lang and market @NotNull


The Object used as a key, LangAndMarket, must override hashCode() and equals(Object _obj)
Add this to LangAndMarket:
    @Override
    public int hashCode()  {
        return (lang+market).hashCode();  // cheezy example
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object _other) {
        ... // the usual way of doing equals()
    }

Then the key generation works.  try removing hashCode() or equals() to make it stop working correctly.
Apparently previous versions of EhCache didn't use hashCode() when calculating the keys.
